# How to query inside a JSON pram string using GraphQL

Tags: mysql, json, filter, graphql

One of the prams that gets returned from a service I call using GraphQL gives back a very long JSON string with 40-60 different data values. I need only need a few of those elements inside the response in order to give back to the UI.

Is there a way to do an exact fetch within that JSON string of only the data I need in Graph vs having to get that entire payload and parsing it within my application?

In the example below, I want to query inside the detailJson pram for foo9: bar39

Example response from Graph

`"Number": 41`

`"CollectionId": 831,`

`"detailJson": "{\"foo1\":bar1,\"foo2\":bar2,\"foo3\": bar3,\"foo4\":bar4,\"foo5\":bar5,\"foo6\": bar6,\"foo7\":bar7,\"foo8\":bar8,\"foo9\": bar39,}`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No.**

GraphQL enables a service to return a JSON value as a string, or even as a custom scalar type. However, doing so negates much of GraphQL's benefits, including being able to request specific selections of the data in question. Unless the service exposes some argument to modify the returned JSON value, there's nothing you, as the client, can do.